# problem using server sent events with nodejs and react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, real-time, server-sent-events

I need to implement `server-sent-events` to my `node js` and react application,
I did some research about this and I had followed some tutorials online especially this [site](https://alligator.io/nodejs/server-sent-events-build-realtime-app/) because of its simplicity.

my goal is that there is 1 route called /api/alert

if we make an HTTP POST request to this route with a JSON object like

```
{
  "longtitude": 100, 
  "latitude": 35, 
  "userId": "5dc28160e8a69c203002383b"
}
```

then the server will store it in the MongoDB and also send it to the client in realtime (using server-sent events of course)

if we make the **HTTP GET** request to this route then it will show all the current objects in **MongoDB** and it will get the new object every time a new object is POST.

it worked like just like how I want it. But a problem came up.
it displays the objects in DB and the new one in real-time just fine until exactly 2 minutes later, somehow the connection is lost or something happens that makes the browser call to the GET /api/alert again then all the same data which is already displayed got displayed again. the duplication happen every 2 minutes as long as i do nothing to it.

i did a lot of research on the

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

and try different ways to work around but it doesn't seem to help at all.

is this a nodejs or react problem. Any idea on what i did wrong or something to do with this problem. All help is appreciated.

these are my code, it is based on most of the what find on this https://alligator.io/nodejs/server-sent-events-build-realtime-app/ :

#### Nodejs code:

```
const { Fire } = require("../models/fire");

let clients = [];

// Iterate clients list and use write res object method to send new nest
function sendEventsToAll(newFire) {
  clients.forEach(c => {
    c.res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(newFire)}\n\n`);
  });
}

module.exports.addAlert = async (req, res, next) => {
  const fire = new Fire(req.body);
  res.send(await fire.save());

  return sendEventsToAll(fire);
};

module.exports.handleAlert = async (req, res, next) => {
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
  };
  res.writeHead(200, headers);
  res.flushHeaders();

  const data = await Fire.find();
  res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);

  // Generate an id based on timestamp and save res
  // object of client connection on clients list
  // Later we'll iterate it and send updates to each client
  const clientId = Date.now();
  const newClient = {
    id: clientId,
    res
  };
  clients.push(newClient);
  console.log(`${clientId} Connection opened`);

  // When client closes connection we update the clients list
  // avoiding the disconnected one
  req.on("close", () => {
    console.log(`${clientId} Connection closed`);
    clients = clients.filter(c => c.id !== clientId);
    res.end();
  });
};
```

#### React code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [nests, setNests] = useState([]);
  const [listening, setListening] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!listening) {
      const events = new EventSource("http://localhost:3900/api/alert");
      events.onmessage = event => {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(event.data);

        setNests(nests => nests.concat(parsedData));
      };

      setListening(true);
    }
  }, [listening, nests]);

  return (
    <table className="stats-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>_id</th>
          <th>longtitude</th>
          <th>latitude</th>
          <th>userId</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {nests.map((nest, i) => (
          <tr key={i}>
            <td>{nest._id}</td>
            <td>{nest.longtitude}</td>
            <td>{nest.latitude}</td>
            <td>{nest.userId}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
export default App;
```

#### Image of the problem I encountered

[image: image of the problem I encountered]

Comment: I tried other tutorials then i encountered the same problem when 2 minutes is passed the browser's console display that error and browser make that HTTP GET again.

Answer (score 2):

Nodejs has 2-minute default timeout that's why your connection has closed after two minutes. If you want it to open for longer period then you need to increase the default timeout.